# How do I trace this recursive method if the input is n=10

Tags: java, recursion, trace

The output is 1024 if I input `n=10`. Please show me how do I trace this code in order to get this answer .

```
static long mystery(int n) {
  if (n==0)
    return 1;

  long temp = mystery(n/2);
  if (n%2==0)
    return temp*temp;
  else
    return 2*temp*temp;
}
```

Comment: Use paper and pencil and note down the variable values while simulating the steps of the computer.

Comment: Why do you want to "trace" the code?  Are you confused about recursion works?

Comment: a little bit, yes.I also have an exam tomorrow and this was a question on a previous exam .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `n` go:
`10 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0` based on basic integer division arithmetics.

The return value of the function therefore is in opposite order:
`1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 32 -> 1024`
`0    1    2    5     10 (values of n)`

Comment: can you please explain how you got the 1024 from the return values

Comment: @danielhanna when n=10 then mystery(5) = 32, 10%2==0, therefore return 32*32 = 1024.